# jQuery: Show 'x' number of labels in a div

Tags: jquery

I have a div as follows

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I use jQuery to add labels to this div as follows.

```
for (i = 0; i < data.Names.length; i++) {
    $('<div>').text($('<label>').text(data.Names[i]).appendTo('#myDiv'));
}
```

Finally, I want to show only 3 labels so I do the following.

```
$('#mydiv label:lt(3)').show();
```

If I do `var count = $('#mydiv label:lt(3)').length`
, count = 3 as expected. However, it shows all the labels rather than just 3.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a sample `running code js snippet` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in your `$('#mydiv label:lt(3)').show();`, there is a typo. it should be `myDiv`.

Secondly, you first need to `hide` other labels so as to only `show` first 3 labels.

Below is a sample snippet:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('<div>').text($('<label>').text(i).appendTo('#myDiv'));
}
$('#myDiv label').hide();
$('#myDiv label:lt(3)').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. My mistake was that I was hiding the div rather than labes, i.e. was doing $('#myDiv').hide().